# Semi-stable model over a totally ramified extension

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, resolution-of-singularities, valuation-theory

**Notation:** Let $R$ be a DVR, $K=\text{Frac}(R)$ and $k=R/\mathfrak{m}$. Given an $R$-scheme $X$, write $X_K=X\times_{R} K$ for the generic fiber and $X_k=X\times_R k$ for the special fiber.

Suppose $k$ is of characteristic $0$.

**Fact:** Let $V$ be a smooth $K$-scheme. By the semi-stable reduction theorem of Kempf, Knudsen, Mumford and Saint-Donat, after replacing $K$ with a finite extension $K'$, one can find a flat $R'$-scheme such that $X$ is regular with generic fiber $V_{K'}$ and the special fiber $X_{k'}$ is a strict normal crossings divisor which is also *reduced*.

My question has to do with the nature of $K'$:

**Question:** Can one take $K'/K$ in (2) to be totally ramified? Moreover, is it true that for *any* given maximal totally ramified extension $L/K$, one can choose $K'$ inside $L$?

For instance, if $K=k((t))$, can one choose $K_n=k((t^{1/n}))$ for a suitable $n\in \mathbb{N}$? (Here $k$ is not necessarily algebraically closed.)